# Show that the counting measure $\zeta$ on $\mathbb{R}^{N}$ is Borel regular.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, borel-measures

I want to show that the counting measure $\zeta$ on $\mathbb{R}^{N}$ is Borel regular.

The counting measure is defined as follows:

[image]

In addition, I know that the counting measure $\zeta$ is not $\sigma$-finite on $ \mathbb{R}^{N}$.

> An outer measure $\mu$ is called Borel measure if all open and thus all Borel sets $\mu$-are measurable. $\mu$ is called Borel-regular if in addition each subset $A \subset \mathbb{R}^{N}$ has a Borel superset $B$ with the same measure. $\mu$ is called open-regular if $B$ in the case $\mu(A)<\infty$ can be chosen in the form $ \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} O_{n}, O_{n}$ open with $A \subset O_{n}, \mu\left(O_{n}\right)<\infty$.

How can I now clearly show that the counting measure $\zeta$ is on $\mathbb{R}^{N}$ Borel regular. Is $\zeta$ also open-regular?

Comment: what's your problem? do you know the definition of Borel regularity?

Comment: @SBF: The definitions are clear to me - I edit them. But how could I prove my question vividly?

Comment: Go vividly about it. Which sets are $\mu$-measurable and which are not?

Comment: For open-regular i must ask you to think about the cardinality of *any* open set, as for borel regular if i understood your definition correctly and as singletons are borel you just need to consider two possible cases for A that ile leave you to figure out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"$\zeta$ is Borel-regular" - All sets are $\zeta$-measurable, because  $\zeta_{\mathbb{R}^{N}}$ is unrestrictedly additive. A set of finite measure is closed, i.e. a Borel set.
The counting measure is not open-regular, since all non-empty open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^{N}$ have infinite measure and there are non-empty sets $A \subset \mathbb{R}^{N}$ with $\zeta(A)<\infty$. In the definition of open regularity, however, the existence of open supersets $O \supset A$ with finite measure is required in particular.